# 477 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios7, linker-errors

I am using google+ api for signing in from google+ [link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started)

but from above link when I add OpenSource directory I got following error.

```
Ld /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/googleIntegration-fkbmbszsnxryxgfuzpeulxiqytcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/googleIntegration.app/googleIntegration normal i386
    cd /Users/Administrator/Desktop/googleIntegration
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/googleIntegration-fkbmbszsnxryxgfuzpeulxiqytcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/googleIntegration-fkbmbszsnxryxgfuzpeulxiqytcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Administrator/Downloads/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.5.1 -filelist /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/googleIntegration-fkbmbszsnxryxgfuzpeulxiqytcn/Build/Intermediates/googleIntegration.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/googleIntegration.build/Objects-normal/i386/googleIntegration.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreText -framework CoreGraphics -framework GooglePlus -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreLocation -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AddressBook -framework UIKit -framework GoogleOpenSource -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/googleIntegration-fkbmbszsnxryxgfuzpeulxiqytcn/Build/Intermediates/googleIntegration.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/googleIntegration.build/Objects-normal/i386/googleIntegration_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/googleIntegration-fkbmbszsnxryxgfuzpeulxiqytcn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/googleIntegration.app/googleIntegration

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.request_ in:
    /Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/googleIntegration-fkbmbszsnxryxgfuzpeulxiqytcn/Build/Intermediates/googleIntegration.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/googleIntegration.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMHTTPFetcher.o
```

I have checked other links and tried their suggestions but I didn't get succeeded?

Can anyone tell me what is the exact problem?

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Please include some of the duplicate symbols in your question.

Comment: @user1954352 You may be copying files to the binary twice. Check your copy files section under your build phases area for the target.

Comment: @TommieC. I have done that task too.

Comment: I had this problem with CocoaPods once. If you are, just delete de Pods folder and run pod install again.